# Getting a Maven dependency in sbt

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I'm trying to get the library discussed [here](https://bitbucket.org/okapiframework/xliff-toolkit/wiki/Getting_Started)

```
<repositories>
 <repository>
  <id>okapi-xliff</id>
   <name>okapi-xliff-repository</name>
   <url>http://repository-okapi-xliff.forge.cloudbees.com/release/</url>                       
   <layout>default</layout>
 </repository>
</repositories>
...
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.okapi.lib</groupId>
  <artifactId>okapi-lib-xliff2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And attempted to convert this to a build.sbt import with

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"net.sf.okapi.lib" % "okapi-lib-xliff2" % "1.0"
)

resolvers += "okapi-xliff" at "http://repository-okapi-xliff.forge.cloudbees.com/release"

resolvers += "websudos-repo" at "http://maven.websudos.co.uk/ext-release-local"
```

I was eventually hitting an error

```
Server access Error: Connection timed out url=http://maven.websudos.co.uk/ext-release-local/net/sf/okapi/lib/okapi-lib-xliff2/1.0/okapi-lib-xliff2-1.0.pom
```

Which I think is ok as websudos is another resolver I have listed. However; it was taking about 10 minutes before the timeout error came; then SBT would just sit there - so I'm not sure if it was trying okapi.

I think I'm pretty close as - `http://repository-okapi-xliff.forge.cloudbees.com/release/net/sf/okapi/lib/okapi-lib-xliff2/1.0/okapi-lib-xliff2-1.0.pom` is a valid URL

So

1) Is there anyway for me to configure SBT to timeout faster?
2) Does my build.sbt look correct? Should it eventually resolve the dependency?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is an issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-735 so, seems the answer is no, you can't set a custom timeout settings.
2. It looks like it is correct, to build it successfully, just remove resolver which is not available now. About build.sbt style: I prefer to use sequences to describe deps / resolvers:

   resolvers ++= Seq(
       "Sonatype OSS Releases"  at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/",
       "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
   )